# How to combine rows in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, row

I have a dataset like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['a', 'b' , 'b', 'a'], 'b': ['a', 'b' , 'b', 'a'] })
```

And i want to combine first two rows and get dataset like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['a b' , 'b', 'a'], 'b': ['a b' , 'b', 'a'] })
```

no rules but first two rows. I do not know how to combine row so i 'create' method to combine by `transpose()` as below

```
db = df.transpose()
db["new"] = db[0].map(str) +' '+ db[1]
db.drop([0, 1], axis=1, inplace=True) # remove these two columns
cols = db.columns.tolist() # re order 
cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
db = db[cols]
df = db.transpose() # reverse operation
df.reset_index()
```

It works but i think there is an easier way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the two rows

```
df.loc[0] = df.loc[0]+ df.loc[1]
df.drop(1, inplace = True)
```

You get

```
    a   b
0   ab  ab
2   b   b
3   a   a
```

A bit more fancy looking :)

```
df.loc[0]= df[:2].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x))
df.drop(1, inplace = True)
```