# Combine Rows by Slicing

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have the following dataframe, and I want to combine multiple rows into one row based on the indexes of the rows, which are stored in a list.

```
df
    Column1
  0 ABC
  1 123
  2 DEF
  3 456
  4 GHI
  5 789
  6 JKL
  7 012
indexes = [[0,3],[4,7]]
```

Preferred output (it's okay if all items are combined into one column):

```
dfn
  Column1
1 ABC 123 DEF 456
2 GHI 789 JKL 012
```

I found this thread: [How to combine rows in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641733/how-to-combine-rows-in-pandas) but it only works for combining two rows (in my dataframe, there are situations where I might be combining 20-30 rows at a time).

Comment: Are all slices equal in size?

Comment: Not necessarily (data is being extracted from a really messy PDF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
idxs = [np.r_[i:j+1] for i, j in indexes]

pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[i].values.T.ravel() for i in idxs])

     0    1    2    3
0  ABC  123  DEF  456
1  GHI  789  JKL  012
```

---

Here's an example with *unequal* slices:

```
indexes = [[0,2], [4,7]]
pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[np.r_[i:j+1]].values.T.ravel() for i, j in indexes])

     0    1    2     3
0  ABC  123  DEF  None
1  GHI  789  JKL   012
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. Can you explain what's going on here?

Comment: @WaltReed I use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to convert your index slice to a range of indices. For example [0, 4] becomes [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. I then use this to index into the dataframe to get all row slices.

Answer (score 1):

By using `IntervalIndex`

```
index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays([0,4],[3,7],closed='both')
G=pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(len(index))),index=index)
df['G']=G.loc[df.index].values
df.groupby('G').Column1.apply(list)
Out[449]: 
G
0    [ABC, 123, DEF, 456]
1    [GHI, 789, JKL, 012]
Name: Column1, dtype: object
```

Also , create the `indexes` by using

```
indexes = np.array([[0,3],[4,7]])
indexes=indexes.T
Out[453]: 
array([[0, 4],
       [3, 7]])
```

Then, You can change

```
index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(indexes[0],indexes[1],closed='both')
```